# TableLayoutPanel C# Highlight/Color Single Cell

Tags: c#, colors, cell, highlight, tablelayoutpanel

Hi hope you can help me out.

Basically i have a table layout panel in windows form application with 6 columns and 10 rows.
Each cell has a picture box in it.

Example of what i want to achieve.

The table represents some sort of pay table the columns represent the multiplier and the rows represent the rank.

So the game starts and the player after doing whats the process of the game is given a score.

The pay table holds all the scores possible and all i want is to highlight that particular cell which holds the score that the player achieved.

I tried a lot but seems that i cannot find a solution to highlight/color a particular cell.

Can you please help me out!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you placing the values into the cells? If they're labels you can change their background with `label.BackColor` (for example 
        `label.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red`), or the text color with `label.ForeColor`.

Comment: i can place them in labels but i cannot find hot to make at the centre the cell when i dock it its still not in the centre

Comment: try using `label.Dock = DockStyle.Fill`.

Comment: I had to use even padding a margining to get it to the right place... but at least it worked.. thanks for your idea!